# How to enable access to datastore for root user

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use the nodejs lib for Datastore from a Compute Engine machine. The code runs well when I run it with my user on the Compute Engine machine. But when I run it with `sudo` I get an error of `Request had insufficient authentication scopes`. Looking at the setting of the machine, I found that the service account of the machine does not have access to Datastore - but no option to enable access!

How do I grant the root user access to Datastore?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set IAM permissions for service accounts in "Developer Console -> IAM & Admin -> IAM".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Service account already set to be the Editor of the project.

Comment: Scope and role are different. Scope is tied with the VM, it determines what the VM can access. The actual permission is the combination of the service account of the program and the scope of the VM where it runs on.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts see access scope in this doc.